# How to fix the ordering between transformed data with MinMaxScaler and actual data?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have some features(X) and output(Y) to be trained in a neural network. Range of the features are different within the X as well as Y. I have scaled X with [MinMaxScaler](https://scikit-learn.org/0.16/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler) say `scaler_x` and Y say `scaler_y`.

After training, I am interested in MSE of 10 different runs for each model. For this I am simply collecting 10 different MSE values and taking their means with `np.mean(errors)`.

Also I am collecting the error in non-scaled version of the data. For this, I am applying `inverse_transform` to the neural network's output and taking:

```
mse_actual = np.mean(np.square(modelpredUnscaled - actualY))
```

After that, the same procedure for scaled (taking mean of 10 errors etc.) is applied.

My question is, for example: for model A, mean value of error for scaled is more than model B but for the same A and B, unscaled mean value of error for A is less than the for B.

A sample plot is here:

[image]

[image]

What can be wrong here? How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I think that nothing is wrong with your model. It is just the choice of modelling (you chose to model with transformed target variable).

AT the same time, your criteria to pick a model should be based on the unscaled version mse, because this is your reality. Getting better performance on the scaled version alone cannot help us anyway.

Hence, choose the model which has best MSE in the unscaled y.